# MongoDB :error doing update (anon):1552 on Update command

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB Version of 1.2.6

I was doing a multiple update on a collection ( If a field named yesterday exists ,update it or else create field called yesterday for that record )

This is my query

```
db.userLoginCount.update({yesterday : {$exists : false}}, {$set: {yesterday : '07082013'}},false,true)
```

Once i run this , i am getting an error as

```
Tue Jul  9 02:43:05 Error: error doing update (anon):1552
```

Please tell me what is wring with the above query ??

Comment: I don't think $exists was in `1.2.6` I think it was in 1.6 or 1.7. Is there a reason why you can't update?

Comment: Thanks a lot , it was production mongodb , and it will take some time to update , is there any alternative for this ??

Comment: `null` might work but there is a difference between whether it exists or is `null` but if it might not matter for your particular case, it will update all docs where the field does not exist or is `null`

Comment: Though I take back my first comment, looking at this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-393 it appears $exists should be there, unfortunately I don't have a version this old anymore to test with